# How to add backbutton in fragment android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I am making one chat application in this i have so many fragments but i am using only one activity.In my application navigation drawer is also there,so my problem is i am going from first fragment to second fragment,in second fragment i am showing backbutton using actionbar homeupenabled,but when i press that backbutton i am not getting any action from onoptionsmenuselected.I am removing drawer toggle when i enter into second fragment by drawerindicator false.I tried in all ways,please help me

code:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment
    {

        private BaseActivity _activity;


        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity)
        {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            _activity= (BaseActivity) activity;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.base, null);
                           _activity._mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            _activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i am doing in activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getActivity().onBackPressed()
```

Comment: i am not getting toast when i press back on fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can do only on thing at time for same activity

```
1)Open drawer event or
2)Back Button
```

Because other are fragments

if you want do do some thing on back press event then you can use overridden method

```
public void onBackPressed()
```

of your activity

Comment: i am removing drawer indicator by setting false

Comment: can i see your activity class?

Answer (score 0):

have you place the second fragment on to the backstack from within your first fragment when you create it? I was having the exact issue that you described. reading over your code I realised I didn't have an override for `onOptionsItemSelected` in my second fragment,but had already called `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in the second fragment. So as soon as I included the `onOptionsItemSelected`. I was able to go back to the first fragment. I even just pasted your home case code in to my second fragment and got the "working" toast in the first.

My only other difference is I do not include an `@Override public View onCreateView`. but that is for different reasons. so my `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` is called in `onActivityCreated` and my first fragment is the main fragment which the activity inflates in its container on create.

calling the second fragment from first is done like so in an `onlistItemClick`

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("SELECTED_TAG", dataList);

        SecondFragment toFragment = new SecondFragment();
        toFragment.setArguments(args);
        //show more about the exercise
        //TODO:start an indent to launch new activity
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slidein, R.anim.slideout);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.container, toFragment, SECOND_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
```

Then the second fragment goes 'back' in the onOptionItemSelected exactly like yours does